# Swap list / string around a character python

Tags: python

I want to swap two parts of a list or string around a specified index, example:

```
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)
```

should return

```
[4, 5, 3, 1, 2]
```

I'm only supposed to have one line of code, it works for strings but I get

can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

when I try to use lists.

```
def swap(listOrString, index):

    return (listOrString[index + 1:] + listOrString[index] + listOrString[:index])
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because you took two slices and one indexing operation and tried to concatenate. slices return sub-lists, indexing returns a single element.

Make the middle component a slice too, e.g. `listOrString[index:index+1]`, (even though it's only a one element slice) so it keeps the type of whatever is being sliced (becoming a one element sequence of that type:

```
return listOrString[index + 1:] + listOrString[index:index+1] + listOrString[:index]
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense

Comment: @AdamSmith This answer specifically doesn't do that to preserve the type being sliced. Eg. your suggestion wouldn't work on a tuple

Comment: @jamylak this is true! And especially since it's designed to work with strings, that was silly of me. Thanks :)

Comment: @AdamSmith I think the variable name used by `OP` wasn't a good one, should just be `sequence` or something

Comment: @jamylak frankly just `s`. Or use annotations: `def swap(s:(list, str), idx:int) -> (list, str): return s[idx+1:] + s[idx:idx+1] + s[:idx]`

Comment: @AdamSmith I think just `s` is fine, or since 1 letter names arent recommended `seq`